# CMake Passing Lists on Command Line

Tags: list, command-line, cmake

I need to run swig as part of my cmake build system. I want the user to be able to specify a list of languages to pass to swig and specify them on the command line.

```
$ cmake -DSWIG_LANGUAGES=java,scala <path to cmake_source_dir>
```

Is there a built-in-way for cmake to handle this?

Comment: Lists are handled in CMake with semicolon. If you use `-DSWIG_LANGUAGES=java;scala;haskell` you can for example iterate over the list with a for loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use semicolons to separate list items. Since semicolon is a special character in unix-like shells, you need to escape it or use quotes. Any of the following commands work:

```
cmake -DSWIG_LANGUAGES=java\;scala ...
cmake "-DSWIG_LANGUAGES=java;scala" ...
cmake '-DSWIG_LANGUAGES=java;scala' ...
```