# How to pass list variable in CMake's execute_process?

Tags: cmake

I want to execute a CMake command in a subdirectory with `execute_process`, and also pass some cache variables as `-D` options.

If the variable is of type string, it works. However, if the variable is a list, the [typical method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248574/1492613) of passing a list in command line does not seem to work.

I tried all of the combinations listed in that answer. I even tried to join `mylist` with  `"\\;"` or `"\\\\;"`. However, the `execute_process` seems to always unpack the `'-DVal2=a\\;b\\;c\\;'` or `'-DVal2=a;b;c'` to `-Dval2=a b c`.

How can I prevent this? Only `-DVal2=a\\;b\\;c` works, but it's very annoying.

```
set(
    mylist
    a
    b
    c
)

set(
    cmake_args
    "-DVal1=abc"
    "'-DVal2=${mylist}'" #does not work, the execute_process will unpack it into seperated args
)

execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${cmake_args} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/subproject
        OUTPUT_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.log
        ERROR_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.log
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subproject
        RESULT_VARIABLE config_result
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape the `;` character which is the default separator for lists in CMake, but it's not clear how you do it so that it doesn't work for you.

So, try something like this

```
set(mylist_str "")

foreach(item ${mylist})
  string(APPEND mylist_str ${item} "\;")
endforeach()

# this is for debugging
message(STATUS "List as string: ${mylist_str}")

set(cmake_args 
    "-DVal1=abc"
    "-DVal2=${mylist_str}"
    "-DVal3=\"${mylist_str}\"" # this has quotes around it
)

# this is for debugging
foreach(item ${cmake_args})
  message(STATUS "A list item: ${item}")
endforeach()
```

Answer (score 4):

Before passing the list, run this line on it:

```
string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" escaped_list "${my_list}")
```

and then pass escaped_list. On the other end, it will have
the exact same value as my_list.

For example,

```
set(my_list "a\;b" "c" "d")
string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" escaped_list "${my_list}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -Dmy_list=${escaped_list} -P test.cmake)
```

(Tested with cmake 3.17).

This also works when assigning first to `cmake_args` and passing that.
For example,

test1.cmake

```
# Construction.
set(my_list "a\;b" "c" "d")
set(other_list "e" "f\;g" "h")

# For debugging purposes.
message("my_list = \"${my_list}\".")
foreach(arg ${my_list})
  message("-> ${arg}")
endforeach()
message("other_list = \"${other_list}\".")
foreach(arg ${other_list})
  message("-> ${arg}")
endforeach()

# Encoding.
string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" escaped_list "${my_list}")
message("escaped_list = \"${escaped_list}\".")

string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" other_escaped_list "${other_list}")
message("other_escaped_list = \"${other_escaped_list}\".")

set(cmake_args "-Dother_list=${other_escaped_list}" "-Dmy_list=${escaped_list}")

execute_process(
  COMMAND
  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${cmake_args} -P test2.cmake
)
```

test2.cmake

```
# For debugging purpose.
message("my_list = \"${my_list}\".")
foreach(arg ${my_list})
  message("-> ${arg}")
endforeach()

message("other_list = \"${other_list}\".")
foreach(arg ${other_list})
  message("-> ${arg}")
endforeach()
```

Output of running `cmake -P test1.cmake` :

```
my_list = "a\;b;c;d".
-> a;b
-> c
-> d
other_list = "e;f\;g;h".
-> e
-> f;g
-> h
escaped_list = "a\\;b\;c\;d".
other_escaped_list = "e\;f\\;g\;h".
my_list = "a\;b;c;d".
-> a;b
-> c
-> d
other_list = "e;f\;g;h".
-> e
-> f;g
-> h
```

Please observe closely where double quotes were and weren't used.